# Sharing Localhost on Network in Windows 7

Tags: networking, iis, localhost

Basically - I am producing a website and I am trying to share the "localhost" port on 2 computers.

Basically, when I build the project I just want to also be able to access it on both computers via the same port.

Currently, I cant seem to be able to do this ? Anyone can help with step-by-step ?

Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding you right you want `localhost` on machines A and B to point to the same place -- This is simultaneously exactly what's happening and completely impossible :-)

`localhost` by convention always points to `127.0.0.1`, the magic loopback IP of the local machine (i.e. 127.0.0.1 on machine A always means machine A; 127.0.0.1 on machine B always means machine B).  It's not an address that can be shared between multiple machines (in fact the entire `127.0.0.0/8` network is reserved for loopback use).

To do what you want you need to connect both machines over a network, assign them non-loopback IPs (private addresses out of `10.0.0.0/8`, `172.16.0.0/12` or `192.168.0.0/16`) & run your service over those addresses.

---

Consult a good networking book for more details...

Comment: hi :) no sorry maybe I made a mistake. Basically on Machine 1 - its 127.0.0.1:81 and I want machine 2 to be able to access this address so it can see the website ?

Comment: Re-read the answer above: `127.0.0.1` is unique to each machine and ***cannot*** be shared across hosts: you ***must*** use non-loopback addresses to do what you want.