# windows 7 IIS to serve pages on my lan

Tags: iis, windows-7

I've searched high and low for an answer to this but I can not find it...which really surprises me...seems like this would be pretty standard.

I have IIS installed in my windows 7 machine and I can browse to things to no end at localhost.  But when I try to pull up a page using the 192.168 address from my LAN, no dice.

I'm relatively new to this version of IIS so not sure if I'm missing something in there.  I also checked in my firewall and enabled something that says "BranchCache Content Retrieval (HTTP-Out)...still no luck.

what am I missing here?

---

ok I added a new rule to my firewall to allow all incoming requests on port 80

I also created a new binding to my ip address in IIS.

still not working...any other ideas?

Comment: well would it make it more on topic if the reason I need to do this is to test code I've written from my daughter's macbook :P  just gotta make sure safari doesn't puke on my stuff.

Comment: This will likely get closed/off-topic, but it *should* be moved to SU. Unfortunately, we can't vote to migrate a question that was just migrated here from SO. SO should have just kicked it over to SU in the first place.

Comment: @Christopher - it was off-topic on SO because it was about setting up IIS properly on your network. It's off topic here because this is for home/personal use.

Comment: Additionally to what @ErikA stated (this site is for "system administrators and desktop support professionals" - this should not have been migrated here, sorry!), it would be helpful to provide details about what error you're getting when trying to load the site in a browser.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a new inbound rule in Windows Firewall that allows port 80.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure

- Your web-site bindings points to your IP-address and/or hostname you want it to be accessible on
- Your firewall does not block incoming connections to port 80
- The router does not block clients from connecting to each other (this is very unlikely)
- Port 80 is not already in use

Answer (score 0):

Your question is similar to this [Sharing Localhost on Network in Windows 7](https://serverfault.com/questions/120782/sharing-localhost-on-network-in-windows-7)

While I can't exactly find the page I got help from, you have to share your localhost folder first. Then you need to add port 8080 to be used to access this site. That should allow you to serve pages on the local network.